# Usage Stats Access permission in android

Tags: android, mobile

I am developing an android application where in, I want to use Usage Stats of android phone. I cannot access it in Android M & above, unless and until user grants me the access.

Is there any way that I can get access without asking the user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can acheive this by setting in your build.gradle file. This will ask user for permission only on the time of installation.

> targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: Usage Stats is to be accessed in Android M and above. If I change targetSdkVersion to 22 then it is not working out for me. I have an issue with higher version and not lower version.

Answer (score 0):

No, the user must grant you access to it.

**NOTE:** Most methods on this API require the permission **android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS**. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device still needs to grant permission through the Settings application.
See [Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS). **Methods which only return the information for the calling package do not require this permission. E.g. [getAppStandbyBucket()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#getAppStandbyBucket()) and [queryEventsForSelf(long, long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager#queryEventsForSelf(long,%20long)).**